# How do I create a slider in the GDK?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Programming the GDK a few weeks now, the `CardScrollView` is a pretty nice interface for displaying cards.  However one issue with the UI is showing the user how far along they are in the card stack.  In the Mirror API, this is nicely handled by the `Slider` view at the bottom of the screen as described on the Glass Design page:

https://developers.google.com/glass/design/style/metrics-grids

Unfortunately, I have not been able to get this `Slider` object to display on the `CardScrollView` and instead have resorted to a klugey `1 of n` text.

Is there any way to get this `Slider` view to display in the GDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, this feature has been already implemented as described in the [original issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=256#c9).

You can use the method `setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled` to show the bar, e.g.

```
mCardScrollView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not yet supported by our API but is currently tracked with [Issue #256](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=256).